# Override Monolog Handler

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to override the Monolog handler BrowserConsoleHandler to customize a little some operations, but my custom static method is clearly not called.
I red that for static classes, inherited classes should use static:: instead self:: for calling down class method, but even by modifying temporarily the base class : my sub method is not called, the super method is called.

I created my custom handler

```
namespace MyBundle\Monolog;
use Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler as BaseBrowserConsoleHandler;
class BrowserConsoleHandler extends BaseBrowserConsoleHandler {
    public static function generateScript(){
          // my custom operation that is not called :[
    }
...
```

then I added my custom handler as a service in config.yml

```
services:
    browser_console_logger:
        class: Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger
        arguments: [special]
        calls:
            - [pushHandler, [@browser_console_handler]]
    browser_console_handler:
        class: MyBundle\Monolog\BrowserConsoleHandler
```

Then I use my logger :

```
    $logger = $this->get('browser_console_logger');
    $logger->info('hello console : ', [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ]);
```

I get my log in the browser console but my sub method has not been called...
I am in dev env and my cache is clear.
I am not very experimented with symfony (yet ;-), I red a few things on this but it seems I am missing something on the way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I found : in the base class Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler, it comes from the way the method chain is called, and in my case, `generateScript()` is called by `send()`, whitch in I changed `self::generateScript` to `static::generateScript.`
But this is not sufficient, send() is called by

```
register_shutdown_function(array('Monolog\Handler\BrowserConsoleHandler', 'send'));
```

so the class context is the base one, we have to change the class name to `get_called_class()`
then the context is my subclass, and finally I have to modify in base class all `private` to  `protected`, I think if the base static class is intended to be inherited it should be like this to work correctly. So it is dependant of Monolog team, I will notice them.